# Почему объекты EF, подгруженные при помощи Lazy Loading, исчезают после вызова ObjectContext.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazyloading

Пример кода:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer : BaseEntity
{
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

public int SummaryId { get; set; }
public virtual Summary Summary { get; set; }  //Lazy loading
}
```

Работа с контекстом:

```
var productsList = context.GetAll<Product>(p => p.Manufacturer).ToList();
//на данном этапе в коллекции содержится коллекция продуктов с
//инициализированными производителями, а у каждого объекта производителя 
//имеется инициализированный объект класса Summary.
```

Но, как только вызывается `ObjectContext.Dispose()`, доступ к объектам, подгруженным при помощи *Lazy loading*, пропадает. Не понимаю, почему, ведь я вызываю `ToList()`, и по идее, все должно подгрузиться из базы в память локально в `IEnumerable<T>`-коллекцию. Подскажите, что делать в такой ситуации? Спасибо.

**Добавлено**
Реализация метода `GetAll`:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(params Expression<Func<T,object>>[] include) where T : BaseEntity
{
    var retVal = this.Set<T>();
    foreach(var item in include)
    {
        retVal = retVal.Include(item);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Используйте List вместо ICollection.

Comment: Возможно у вас var productsList не используется и Сборщик мусора его удаляет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список объектов `Manufacturer` при вызове `ToList()` подгружается и после `Dispose` никуда не исчезает. Но значения свойств `Summary` для этих объектов при вызове ToList не подгружаются.

Механизм Lazy Loading организует подргрузку данных *по необходимости*, при обращении к ним в коде. Нет обращения - явного вызова `Summary` - данные остаются незагруженными.

Как работает Lazy Loading:

1. При загрузке `Manufacturer` вызовом `ToList()` или, например, `Single()`, вместо объекта `Manufacturer` вы получаете сгенерированный класс-наследник с переопределенным свойством `Summary`.
2. Свойство переопределено так, что при обращении оно проверяет - был ли в текущем контексте уже загружен этот объект `Summary`.
3. Если был загружен - отдает его.
4. Если не был - загружает.

Очевидно, что 2-4 не будет работать после уничтожения контекста. Т.е. Lazy Load - отложенная загрузка - работает только при живом контексте. Именно потому, что она отложенная "на потом", и для срабатывания при наступлении этого "потом" ей нужен контекст.

Применительно к вашему коду - правильный комментарий выглядит так:

```
var productsList = context.GetAll<Product>(p => p.Manufacturer).ToList();
//на данном этапе в коллекции содержится коллекция продуктов с
//инициализированными производителями, а у каждого объекта производителя 
//имеется *неинициализированный* объект класса Summary.
```

---

Дополнение от @PavelMayorov:

вот так должно заработать:

```
context.GetAll<Product>(p => p.Manufacturer.Summary).ToList();
```

---

Аналог без вспомогательного метода `GetAll<T>`:

```
var productsList = context.Products
    .Include(p => p.Manufacturer.Summary)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @klutch1991 вызовом Include - сейчас допишу пример

Comment: @klutch1991 хм, не допишу - EF не умеет делать Include в таком случае :(

Comment: мне кажется что может помочь `load()` в этом случае, т.е. сначала получаем список продуктов, потом для него подгружаем остальные данные

Comment: @klutch1991, так не используйте LazyLoad, либо после загрузки сразу пройдитесь по всем объектам и пообращайтесь к свойству Summary

Comment: @klutch1991 посмотрите [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) *Explicitly Loading* мне кажется это Ваш случай

Comment: @klutch1991 [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, я просто почему-то решил что GetAll - это Select, а не обертка поверх Include. Incude + Select вроде не работает. Перенесу ваш код в ответ, если вы не против?